# How do I make this button works

Tags: reactjs

Well I have a function in a folder named `auth` that contain an `auth.js` file with this function:

```
logout() {
    // Clear Access Token and ID Token from local storage
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
    localStorage.removeItem('expires_at')
    localStorage.removeItem('chatkit_user')
    //TODO: callback to reset the app state.
}
```

Then I have a button in another folder with this code:

```
<button onClick={ logout() } >
    Log Out
</button>
```

Now how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the ()

```
<button onClick={logout} >
```

If your function is in the same class of the render

```
<button onClick={this.logout} >
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function that will be called every time the button is clicked.

Instead, currently you are calling the function immediately, and then passing the result of that call.

One approach would be to wrap the attribute with an arrow function, like so:

```
<button onClick={() => logout()} >
  Log Out
</button>
```

Or pass the function directly without calling it (note, this will not work properly when you pass class methods, you would need to bind them first):

```
<button onClick={logout} >
  Log Out
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `onClick` with the following syntax, then the `logout` function will be called on each render:

```
<button onClick={ logout() }>Log Out</button>
```

So my suggestion would to use just like the following if you have a functional component:

```
<button onClick={ () => logout() }>Log Out</button>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

< button onClick={() => logout() } >  Log Out < /button>

() => logout(), this basically returns you a function which will be called on click, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understood you'r question you want to create a logout function
so
for Html part

```
<button onClick="logout()">logout</button>
```

for Javascript

```
function logout() {
 window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
 window.localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
 window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
 window.localStorage.removeItem("chatkit_user");

}
```

if i'm wrong tell me so i'll give you a another one :)

Comment: hii well it is a log out in react the function is there i just wanna join them the function is in a folder named auth and my button in another i did try import and the location but it send me error

Comment: https://github.com/Cazadorx/chatkit-sample-client/blob/master/src/auth/auth.js

Comment: https://github.com/Cazadorx/chatkit-sample-client/blob/master/src/components/UserHeader/index.js